# library(knitr) Error in library(knitr) : there is no package called ‘knitr’

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the knitr package and I'm getting an error.  It ran through many packages then said this:

Warning in install.packages :
  write error in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  write error in extracting from zip file
Error in install.packages : subscript out of bounds

> library(knitr)
>   Error in library(knitr) : there is no package called ‘knitr’

Then I tried this(it worked on the swirl package previously):

> install.packages("knitr",type="win.binary")
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/knitr_1.20.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 893090 bytes (872 KB)
>   downloaded 872 KB

Warning in install.packages :
  write error in extracting from zip file

The downloaded binary packages are in
     C:\Program Files (x86)..........

> library(knitr)
>   Error in library(knitr) : ‘knitr’ is not a valid installed package

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Try changing your CRAN mirror; 2) Try navigating into your R install directory and blowing away the old `knitr` folder, then trying the install again.

Comment: Tried that......got this:

Comment: > .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library"
> install.packages(knitr)
Error in install.packages : object 'knitr' not found
Warning message:
In read.dcf(file.path(p, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Version")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library/knitr/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. Are you using RStudio? If not, you should try it... I spent a whole weekend fighting issues like this when I was trying to get miktex and Rmarkdown to work, and when I went into RStudio, there were no problems at all. Just a thought.

Comment: yeah I'm in RStudio

Comment: This sounds like a permissions issue to me. Are you on a corporate machine where you don't have the ability to write to the C drive?

Comment: Yes I am.  I'm going to try it on my personal laptop tonight.  Maybe that IS the issue.